# How to remove data- elements from html

Tags: javascript, html

I have an href with data-toggle="dropdown", which I'm trying to remove.
This snippet doesn't seem to work:

```
$(document).on('click','a',function() {
$(this).data('toggle','Phillip Senn');
});
```

Instead, Firebug is showing that data-toggle still equals "dropdown" and there is a new "toggle" attribut equal to "Phillip Senn".

What I'd like to do is remove it altogether.

Comment: If you showed us your HTML, we might know that you had a data-toggle attribute on the HTML element that also has to be addressed.  Come on people, if you don't show us your HTML, you WONT necessarily get a complete or best answer - always.

Comment: What do you mean by remove it from HTML? Are you actually trying to remove the attribute from the `a` element? Or the property from the `dataset` of the element? Or do you want to clear it from jQuery's `.data()` store? These are all different.

Comment: Ah.  I found a solution.  I can use the removeAttr('data-toggle') to remove it.

Comment: Yeah, I thought they were the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've got an attribute on the HTML and you want to remove both it and the jQuery data, then you would use this:

```
this.removeAttribute("data-toggle");
$(this).removeData('toggle');
```

Only, the jQuery data is updated with subsequent writes to `.data()`, but if you want to remove the attribute that was originally on the HTML object, then you have to call `removeAttribute()` too.

Answer (score 2):

I think it goes something like this...

```
$(this).removeData('toggle');
```

To remove an attribute:

```
$(this).removeAttr("the-name-of-the-attribute");
```

Comment: That removes the data that I added, but it doesn't remove the data-toggle attribute or value.

Answer (score 2):

[removeData](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.removeData/)

I do not understand how people can spend time posting a question when googling [jquery remove data](http://riii.nl/5mk3x) and clicking the first result would give them the answer in only a fraction of the time...

Comment: I know.  You'd think that JavaScript would be so simple, wouldn't you?  Vote for Pedro!

Comment: In their example, they've added the data using the jQuery.data command.  But in my case, it's a data-toggle attribute.  I'm wondering if that's the reason it doesn't work.

Comment: @Pedro: [this](http://jsfiddle.net/NPJjX/) works perfectly fine. If it doesn't work for you then you need to state your problem more clearly and provide a testcase that actually reproduces the problem. We're no psychics ;-)

Comment: The correct link to the documetnation is not the first result; the one pointed is the low-level function (either yours **and** the LMGTFY links). What the user needs is the [.removeData()](https://api.jquery.com/removeData/). *And it's worth mentioning that for actually removing from the DOM (and not just from the jQuery cache) is also needed to run [.removeAttr](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/).*